# is it possible to have child table in a parent table

Tags: jsp, displaytag

Is it possible to create a displaytag table with embedded child table ? Example below is to create an Employee report with his/her contact means as child table.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display"%>
<display:table id="employees" name="employees" uid="1">
    <display:column title="Id" property="employeeId" />
    <display:column title="Department" property="department" />
    <display:column title="Contact Points" property="contacts">
    <display:table id="contacts" name="contacts" uid="2">
        <display:column title="Postal Address" property="postalAddress" />
        <display:column title="Email" property="emailAddress" />
        <display:column title="Cell Phone" property="cellPhoneNumber" />
    </display:table>
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

Comment: I think the nested table data is not exported? Any option to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create displaytag nested tables:
just follow [this](http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.1/example-nestedtables.jsp) example